# Add new column in dataframe based on dataframe group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Given the dataframe **df**

```
userid    tripid    Transportation_Mode    Altitude
  1         1            walk                20
  1         1            walk                22
  1         1            walk                22
  1         1            bike                24
  1         1            bike                22
  1         1            walk                25
  1         1            walk                27
  1         1            walk                22
  1         1            car                 26
  1         1            car                 21
  1         1            car                 27
  1         2            car                 22
  1         2            car                 24
  1         2            car                 22
  1         2            walk                22
  1         2            walk                24
  2         1            bike                27
  2         1            bike                21
  2         1            bike                26
```

I like to add new column **segmentid** like this

```
userid    tripid    Transportation_Mode    Altitude    Segmentid
  1         1            walk                20            1
  1         1            walk                22            1
  1         1            walk                22            1
  1         1            bike                24            2
  1         1            bike                22            2
  1         1            walk                25            3
  1         1            walk                27            3
  1         1            walk                22            3
  1         1            car                 26            4
  1         1            car                 21            4
  1         1            car                 27            4
  1         2            car                 22            1
  1         2            car                 24            1
  1         2            car                 22            1
  1         2            walk                22            2
  1         2            walk                24            2
  2         1            bike                27            1
  2         1            bike                21            1
  2         1            bike                26            1
```

A Segment is the sequence of numbers starting from 1 for each user. A user has multiple trips and each trip consists of multiple transportation modes. Whenever user changes the transportation mode, it should increment by 1. When a tripid or userid changes, it should restart from 1.

I try using this code but not getting the right result.

```
df['segmentid'] = df.groupby([userid,tripid]).Transportation_Mode.apply(lambda x: x.ne(x.shift(1)).cumsum())
```

Comment: please edit the last segment of code and give an explicit definition of what segment is. Apparently you want to map when a user's trip changes transportation method, correct?

Comment: Thanks. I change my question accordingly. When a transportation mode in user's trip changes, it increments by 1.

Comment: Your code  is working fine with me

Comment: I used your code and I can't see where it's failing

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake while analyzing the result, perhaps something gonna overlook in huge dataset.

Comment: The only problem with your code is that it is slow, might not be a good option for big data sets

Comment: Is there alternative for that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it exactly but I might have an idea or two.
In order to add new Column you can use `withColumn(colName, col)` function. This function will create a new column with a value that can be decided using a `UDF UserDefinedFunction` as below:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
squared_udf = udf(squared, LongType())
df = sqlContext.table("test")
display(df.select("id", squared_udf("id").alias("id_squared")))
```

However, in your case you have to count the number of distinct group before adding the new column. In your case, you can create a `Dict` in order to store each group and the corresponding value you want to give. Then in the UDF you can assign each record the matching value.

Look for `WithColumn()` and `UDF` function to solve your issue.